# If I want write a programming language, what I have to know?

Tags: programming-languages

I think about to take this course on coursera:

https://www.coursera.org/course/compilers

What knowledge I absolutely have to have in order to succeeded in this class?

In particularly I'd like to see something like this:

- mathematical subject required
- engineering/CS required (data structures and so on)

Thanks in advance, Nick.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Where to start?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)**

Comment: Why would you need mathematical subject to write a compiler - aside from being able to understand basic expressions like `a + b * c` or `x = y / z + 5`, I don't see much maths skills needed in compilers. I certainly won't hurt if you know a bit of math, but requirement, don't think so (obviously, if you want to write optimisation steps for specific math expressions, yes, knowing that `1-sin(x)` == cos(x)` or whatever, may help - but that's not essential for compiler writing in general)

Comment: Like the "What do I need to know" in the FAQ below the course description, you should be familiar with writing code in general, not just a few snippets, but larger chunks too. I would hope that the course actually contains the building blocks you need to go from "being a reasonably competent general programmer" to "being able to write (most parts of) a compiler".

Comment: Buy The Dragon Book - accept no substitutes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could/should read up on the following topics for preparation:

- finite state machines
- formal and context-free grammar
- parse tree
- Extended Backus–Naur Form

For a start you could examine the *scheme* language. It is pretty easy to parse and analyse. You could develop something similar.

Comment: Also, extensive experience with the state of the art (other languages, all paradigms) is important.

Comment: You should also read about [programming language pragmatics](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/) & read [Lisp in Small Pieces](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html)